# Printing simplified DAG plot with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a long snakemake workflow processing 9 samples with many parallel rules. When I create a picture for the DAG with:

```
snakemake --forceall --dag | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf
```

the resulting dag plot is huge and very redundant (and ugly because of complex node placement).

Is it possible to produce a canonical dag plot that will not show the 9 nodes for each task but only the main path through all steps?

I thought od simplifying my sample list to one sample but hope there is a better method without touching the snakefile (secret parameters?)

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the flag `--rulegraph` instead of `--dag`.

Comment: never crossed this in my snakemake readings (obviously still insufficient). THANKS YOU

Comment: Is it possible to set the orientation of the dag graphs as horizontal i.e. flowing from left to right instead of top to bottom? This might help in reducing the complexity (clutter) of the dag graphs.

Comment: In my experience, the width of the dag graphs becomes huge and unmanageable.